# Tikz coordinates, arrows, and stopping short

Tags: tikz-pgf

So, I'm drawing velocity arrows with labels over them.

The minimal example is that I have a node (a) and I want an arrow pointing towards the origin, but only part way. The distance could be long or short, maybe based on the magnitude of velocity. I've found a solution, but I want to know what others are out there, because it's not that elegant and LaTeX-y.

What I just got working is this line:

```
\draw[->, shorten >=1cm] (a) -- (0,0)
node [near start, sloped, above] {12 m/s};
```

The parts I dislike about this solution are that I'm specifying how much to reduce the length rather that its actual length, and that as the length varies I have to change the label position, when I really just want it centered on the arrow length.

I'm imagining there might be some way to specify a relative polar coordinate as "towards that point, this long" instead of explicit angle. Any ideas?

Comment: It is always compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Instead of `near start` just use `midway`.  Does that yield the result you are looking for?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `<coordinate>!<number>!<second coordinate>`
syntax; for example `(3,3)!.25!(0,0)` means "the coordinate that is one quarter on the way from `(3,3)` to `(0,0)`". To place the label in the middle of the arrow, use the `midway` option. An example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (3,3);
\coordinate (b) at (3,0);
\coordinate (c) at (-3,3);
\node (O) at (0,0) {origin};
\draw[->,red] (3,3) -- ( $ (a)!.25!(0,0) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {12 m/s};
\draw[->,blue] (b) -- ( $ (b)!.8!(0,0) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {12 m/s};
\draw[->,magenta] (c) -- ( $ (c)!.5!(0,0) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {12 m/s};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Even closer to waht you need, is the `<coordinate>!<dimension>!<second coordinate>` syntax, which means "use the point that is distanced
`<dimension>` from `<coordinate>` on the straight line from `<coordinate>` to `<second coordinate>`". A little example: 
:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (b) at (3,0);
\node (O) at (0,0) {origin};
\draw[->,magenta] (b) -- ( $ (b)!3cm!(0,0) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {12 m/s};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And, of course, you can wrap this in a macro, as the following example suggests. The `\arrowfromto[<attributes>]{<initial coordinate>}{<to coordinate>}{<distance>}{<label>}` macro will apply `\draw` with the options given in the first optional argument, from `<initial coordinate>` to a point that is `<distance>` far away from it and on the straight line from `<initial coordinate>` to the `<to coordinate>, using a label given by``:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% syntax
% \arrowfromto[<attributes>]{<initial coordinate>}{<to coordinate>}{<distance>}{<label>}
\newcommand\arrowfromto[5][blue]{%
  \draw[#1] #2 -- ( $ #2!#4!#3 $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {#5}}
\coordinate (a) at (3,3);
\node (O) at (0,0) {$O$};
\node (a) at (0,3) {$a$};
\node (b) at (3,3) {$b$};
\arrowfromto{(O)}{(a)}{5cm}{5cm};
\arrowfromto[-latex,red]{(a)}{(b)}{3cm}{3cm};
\arrowfromto[<->,green!80!black]{(b)}{(O)}{10mm}{10mm};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]